# ASP.NET Core 2.0 unable to check if user is in role properly in Razor view or controller [authorize] annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a legacy project with roles based authorization but I'm having some issues.  `User.IsInRole("admin")` and `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` always failing Authorization. the `User.IsInRole()` always returns `False`. I'm pretty sure that user was properly added to the role. `Role name 'admin' is already taken.` `User already in role 'admin'.`

Maybe some service are influencing another.

Here is my startup.cs resumed code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connetctionString));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env){
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc(routes => {...});
}
```

What am I missing?

PS. Yes, I logged ou and login.

PS. Yes the user is in the role admin

PS. the "admin" are correct in lowercase

PS. ApplicationDbContext inherits IdentityDbContext

Ps2. Here is my Data

```
SELECT id,username FROM aspnetusers;

|id          | username        |
|c4f7bf16... | admin@admin.com |

SELECT Id,Name FROM aspnetroles;

|Id          | Name  |
|50e2a572... | admin |

SELECT * FROM aspnetuserroles;

|UserId      | RoleId     |
|c4f7bf16... | 50e2a572...|
```

Comment: Share us the records in database to make sure you have added `admin` role to the user. As the suggestion from @Munendra Kumar, output all the cliams to see whether you have `admin` role for the User.

Comment: Make sure you have logged out and then back in again after adding the user to the admin role

Comment: Yes I did it. and edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of mistakes I finally found what I was missing.

I was extending only `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>`not `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>`.

After correct extending the roles was able to be claimend.

```
public class MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that this is because your `Roles` and your `Claims` are mixed up somewhere.

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.isinrole?view=netcore-2.1#System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_IsInRole_System_String_) the ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole() method checks for Claims of type `ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType`.

It is possible to set a Claim of "admin" without it being of ClaimType `ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType` in which case it will fail authentication.

Comment: it seems to be more accurate. I will test on this way

Answer (score 1):

identity server configured to return role in claims after authentication.you can check claim in the controller.

Like this

```
var claims = User.Claims.ToList();
```

Comment: how does this will help me with `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` controllçer data annotation?

Comment: Hi Daniel,
This (var claims = User.Claims.ToList()) will not help to Authorization of user but it provides you list of all available claims, may I know which type of authentication mechanism are you using?

Answer (score 1):

One more possible for your issue, please check whether your role name is `admin`.

For `Authorize` or `User.IsInRole`, it is case-sensitive, which means if your role name is `Admin`, it will fail for `User.IsInRole("admin")` or `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]`.

For one way to check whether it is `admin`, try `await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "user")` :

```
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

        var r1 = User.IsInRole("User");
        var r2 = User.IsInRole("user");
        var r3 = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "user");
```

You may try to define `role` as const to avoid case missmatch.